# PresentViewController with Tabbar and Navigationbar iOS

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am presenting a view controller class using custom navigation bar as follow:

```
CreateShiftRosterEventViewController *objDetailView = [[CreateShiftRosterEventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CreateShiftRosterEventViewController" bundle:nil];

CustomNavigationViewController *navcont = [[CustomNavigationViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objDetailView];

// Set the user default to 1 to support landscape orientation also for next view
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"orientationView"];

[self presentViewController:navcont animated:YES completion:nil];

[objDetailView release];objDetailView = nil;
[navcont release];navcont=nil;
```

but it hides tab bar at CreateShiftRosterEventViewController class.

Can anyone please help me, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have created navigationcontroller but you cann't add on view. This is the reason to hide.

Answer (score 0):

You might have added the tab bar, but its not visible because of its autoresize setting. It must be aligned towards bottom of the screen.

You can find the screen shot attached below.

[image: Autoresize Setting]